# Displaying lxdm login screen on both monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, login-screen

I want my lxdm login screen to appear on both monitors so that I can login whichever monitor happens to be turned on, which xrandr seems unable to determine.

With xdm, I could accomplish this by adding a line

```
xrandr --output DP-2 --auto --pos 0x0 --output DP-1 --auto --pos 0x0
```

to /etc/X11/xdm/Xsetup, DP-1 and DP-2 being the xrandr names for the two displays.

With lxdm, I tried to add this line to /etc/lxdm/LoginReady and to /etc/lxdm/PreLogin, but this made no difference. On DP-1, I get the login screen, while DP-2 remains black, although I can move the mouse pointer to it.

Ubuntu version 20.04. Installed as Lubuntu but now with most of lxqt removed, and  fvwm as window manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it via xorg, with a file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf with contents:

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier  "DP-1"
  Option      "Position" "0 0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier  "DP-2"
  Option      "Position" "0 0"
EndSection
```

where  DP-1 and DP-2 were again the xrandr names of the video outputs.